# List of numbers component on Swing

Tags: java, swing, jspinner

I want to show the same as the input type number of HTML5 but on Swing. 
This image illustrate what I want to do:

[image: and the number is going from 0 to 999 for example]

and the number is going from 0 to 999 for example

How can I make the same using Java Swing?

Comment: Are you expecting to write full program for you?

Comment: @afzalex what's your problem ?  did i ask for the full program! im looking for the trick to get my problem solved and i have found it.

Comment: Here is the documentation to learn how it could be done [dcos](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/spinner.html)

Comment: LOL! Please don't get angry. I didn't mean to make you sad. Sorry!

Comment: @afzalex thank you for the documentation. No I'm not :) its ok

Comment: @afzalex  Nice call on the link to the tutorial..

Comment: @Souad  Since you seem to know how to progress from here, you might consider either writing up an answer, or deleting the question.  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public class MyFrame(){

        SpinnerModel spinnerModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(0,0,999,1);
        JSpinner anlist = new JSpinner(spinnerModel);
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();

        public MyFrame(){

                 panel1.add(anlist);

                        }

}
```